# How to remove __ci_last_regenerate

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have downloaded register login and logout of an already developed codeigniter setup. Everything is working fine on my local env. But on each page codeigniter is showing this message

`array(1) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1463482771) }`

or after login

```
array(6) { ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=> int(1463483076) ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["username"]=> string(7) "mangesh" ["logged_in"]=> bool(true) ["is_confirmed"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) }
```

How can I remove or hide "__ci_last_regenerate" ???

Already developed codeigniter setup  https://github.com/hedii/Codeigniter-login-logout-register

Comment: which functions prints you this?

Comment: there is nothing like echo or print_r or var_dump in view and in controller! I dont know from where codeigniter in echoing this array !!!!

Comment: can add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code in your `views/header.php` file is the culprit:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION)) : ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>
                </div>
            </div><!-- .row -->
        </div><!-- .container -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, tht's the culprit. Thanks.